# Canon T3i: Why would shots I took be missing on the card?

Tags: canon, memory-card, canon-600d

I just got my first DSLR-Canon T3i and I've been going out and shooting to learn.  Generally coming along well.  However, there are a few shots that I know I took that just aren't on the card.  Any idea why they didn't save to the card? Thanks for ideas.

Comment: How are you viewing the images on the card? Using the camera or an application on a computer? If on a computer are the images transferred or being viewed from the card (using the camera as a drive or a card reader)? What application on the computer are you using to view the images? There are a lot of undiscussed variables that could have a bearing on the answer to your question.

Comment: If you did not to a lot of deleting when you were taking the photos, check the numbers in the filenames and see if there are gaps in the sequence where there shouldn't be. If there aren't gaps in numbers and you thought the photo isn't there and it should be, then you probably didn't take it

Answer (score 1):

Hypotheses:

- Bad blocks on the memory card. When this happens, it usually leaves broken rather than missing image files. If you put the memory card into a computer, do you see files corresponding to the missing images? Usually the files are sequentially numbered. There are computer programs you can run to exercise the entire SD card, looking for bad blocks. Such a utility can take those blocks out of service, but in practice it's better to throw out the bad memory card and get a better one. I've had good results from Sandisk; not so good results from Patriot.
- Someone deleted those images from the memory card. When that happens, there will be gaps in the sequential file names. Possible exception: Deleting an image before taking the next one. A quick test would show if the next one gets the next sequential photo number or reveals the gap.
- Perhaps you captured some of the photos in JPEG format and others in RAW format. Then when you look at the SD card in, say, Windows Explorer, it will show all the files but it will only show the JPEGs as photos. It doesn't know what to do with the RAW photos.
- Maybe you didn't capture those shots after all? If you press the shutter button half way to focus, then don't press it the rest of the way to shoot, it could be confusing. Also, when the camera doesn't have enough light to focus, pressing the shutter doesn't take a picture.